# how to implement a search function for a field of type many2one?

Tags: python, postgresql, search, odoo, openerp-7

im trying to implement a simple search function in open erp 7. It will search and list all records based on management code, but the problem is management code is a type many2one and its a field in another model. when i run it, it gives me an error like this below.What do i need to change to make it work?

ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer ~~* unknown LINE 1: ...t_org_table" WHERE ("budget_org_table"."management_code" ilike '%12... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

my xml code

```
<record id="feature_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">management.feature_inventory.search</field>
    <field name="model">management.feature_inventory</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Feature Inventory">
            <field name="management_unit_code" string="Management Unit Code"/>
            <field name="year" string="Year"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

my model

```
class feature_inventory(osv.osv):

    _name = "management.feature_inventory"
    _description = "Feature Inventory"
    _rec_name = "feature_code"
    _columns = {
        'feature_code': fields.many2one("budget.feature_details","Code",
                                        required=True),
        'management_unit_code': fields.many2one("budget.org_table",
                                                "Management Unit Code", 
                                                required=True),       
        'Total': fields.integer("Total"),
        'condition_1': fields.integer("Condition 1"),
        'condition_2': fields.integer("Condition 2"),
        'condition_3': fields.integer("Condition 3"),
        'year': fields.integer("Year", size=64, required=True),
    }
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('feature_code_unique', 'UNIQUE(feature_code)',
         'Each feature_code is unique.'),
    ]
```

please help...

Comment: What I can see from your code is that the field `management_code` from your xml file is named `management_unit_code` in you Python code.

Comment: @ Andrei Boyanov, sorry, i fixed that, and its still not working? any idea?

Comment: Did the error changed to `..."budget_org_table"."management_unit_code" ilike...`?

Comment: yes. but i managed to fix it already...anyway,thanks for the help @ Andrei Boyanov